# Can I use SpringEL's boolean or operator with Spring security's @Preauthorize?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

When I tried to use the "or" operator in my @Preauthorize annotation I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#authenticatingUser.id == #id or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')'
```

I think my syntax is correct as shown by the "or" examples in the below docs.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

And Spring Security says explicitly that it uses "Spring EL expressions"

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

But I haven't seen any examples online of people using the boolean "or" operator in an @Preauthorize annotation.

Here's the controller code for completeness. Ostensibly I want a user to be able to change their own password, or an admin. I have successfully used both the the `#authenticatingUser.id == #id` and the `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` on their own, but with the or I get an error.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("#authenticatingUser.id == #id or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public User newPassword(@PathVariable int id, @RequestParam String newPassword, @ModelAttribute User authenticatingUser) {
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    user.setPassword(newPassword);
    return userService.save(user);
}
```

Comment: 1. Do you have this `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` ? 2. Can you show more StackTrace ? I don't think that issue is around `or` operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed use the EL as shown above, with the `or` as written. The `#` accessor works for primitives the way you would expect. The problem I had was unrelated to the SpringEL expression's construction.

```
@PreAuthorize("#authenticatingUser.id == #id or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public User newPassword(@PathVariable int id, @RequestParam String newPassword, @ModelAttribute User authenticatingUser) {
```